# I don't know what is happening when is tried to upgrade pip fro 20.2.2 to 20.2.3 is showing errors

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\sulav>python get-pip.py
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\sulav>python -m pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.2
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\sulav\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\pip.exe
   from C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-plw0b_z7\pip.exe
  Moving to c:\users\sulav\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\pip3.7.exe
   from C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-plw0b_z7\pip3.7.exe
  Moving to c:\users\sulav\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\pip3.exe
   from C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-plw0b_z7\pip3.exe
  Moving to c:\users\sulav\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\pip-20.2.2.dist-info\
   from c:\users\sulav\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\~ip-20.2.2.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\sulav\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\pip\
   from c:\users\sulav\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\~ip
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 421, in run
    pycompile=options.compile,
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 90, in install_given_reqs
    pycompile=pycompile,
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 821, in install
    requested=self.user_supplied,
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 860, in install_wheel
    requested=requested,
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 762, in _install_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 418, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 498, in make
    return super(PipScriptMaker, self).make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 407, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 307, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 242, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 386, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\sulav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download `get-pip.py` and make sure that you are in that directory when you are trying to install it. For instance i see that the dirctory you are in is `C:\Users\sulav>` make sure that it is downloaded to this directory.